# Check the value of a string passed in from an external source

Tags: c#, string

I'm getting a message being sent to my program from an external device and I need to check what the string message is.

What is the process I need to do to this?

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
string read_in_value;

void ReadInMessage(string message)
{
  read_in_value = message;
  if( read_in_value == /* the message value being sent in */ )
  {
      // DO SSTUFF
  }
}
```

I know normally it would be a case of putting `if (read_in_value == message)` but I need to check the actual message that is being read in. The value being sent could be one of two things I need to check against.

Comment: You should add more tags.

Comment: This seems unclear. Can you add some more info about what exactly it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, care to elaborate? `if (read_in_value == message)` would always be true, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have multiple values,these is way to check the string :

```
List<string> answervalue=new List<string>;
answervalue.ADD("firstthing")
answervalue.ADD("secondthing")…………

if(answervalue.contains(/*the message value being send it*/)
{
//do some thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( read_in_value == "firstthing" ||  read_in_value == "secondthing" )
{
    // DO SSTUFF
}
```

or

```
void ReadInMessage(string message)
{
  if( message == "firstthing" || message == "secondthing" )
  {
      // DO SSTUFF
  }
}
```